# Use jQuery to add data to elasticsearch index

Tags: jquery, elasticsearch

I want to add data as well as update my elasticsearch index.
Since I'm not very experienced with the elasticsearch clients, I try to handle everything with jQuery.

To add data, I first check for the highest `id`, and then I want to send a JSON object via PUT.

```
var persondata = { 
    "field1": $('#field1').val(),
    "field2": $('#field2').val(),
    "field3": $('#field3').val()
};

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'http://localhost:9200/_search',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify( { "query" : { "match_all" : {} }, "sort": [ { "_uid": "desc" } ] } )
})
.done(function( result ){
    var highestid = parseInt(result.hits.hits[0]._id, 10) + 1;

    $.ajax({
        type: "PUT",
        url: 'http://localhost:9200/mytable/persons/'+ highestid,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify( persondata )
    });
});
```

To add data via curl, I found the following code:

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/movies/movie/1" -d'
{
    "title": "The Godfather",
    "director": "Francis Ford Coppola",
    "year": 1972
}'
```

(Source: http://joelabrahamsson.com/elasticsearch-101/)

Since my code is not working, I'm wondering if I need the "-d" after the `id` too. Of course I tried to simply add this, but it doesn't work.
What is this "-d" for?
Also, what do I have to do to add data to my elasticsearch index via jQuery?

Comment: You don't need to create an id. ES will create a unique id for you.

Comment: -d is to tell the command line not to send the command until the close quote. Only needed for the command line.

Comment: Use the 'sense' plugin for chrome browser to test all your elasticsearch work. It is awesome. I would not use jquery until your queries are tight.

Comment: I have to rethink my data structure and check if I really need a "useful" id or if I can use the generated - of course it would be faster to use the generated one.
I already used the sense plugin and my code works there. I just figured out there was a problem with empty values - so it now works.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code for create or update the data :

```
$.ajax({

        type: "PUT",
        async: false,
        url: 'http://{localhost}:9200/twitter/tweet/9',
        data: JSON.stringify({"user" : "kimchy","post_date" : "2009-11-15T14:12:12","message" : "trying out Elasticsearch"}),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (msg) 
                { 
                    alert("the json is "+ msg._index);
                    $('#stage').html(msg._index );
                    $('#stage').append(" type : "+msg._type );
                    $('#stage').append(" id :"+msg._id)
                },
        error: function (err)
        { alert(err.responseText)}
    });
```

Remember that must put the index, the type and id on the url.